# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Terraform DisableIMDSv1 Unknown Configuration Setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I'm trying to disable IMDSv1 in an ElasticBeanstalk Module I'm writing. I'm looking at the available EB auto scaling setting options [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration). It shows that the DisableIMDSv1 is a valid setting but when I run a `terraform apply` it's giving me this error.

```
ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'DisableIMDSv1'): Unknown configuration setting.
        status code: 400
```

I'm using a variable to loop through my settings so this is what the variable code with the DisableIMDSv1 looks like.

```
    launch_configuration = {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
      value     = "some-role"
    }
    disable_imds_v1 = {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name      = "DisableIMDSv1"
      value     = "true"
    }
```

If I comment out the disable_imds_v1 part I can successfully run my `terraform apply`.

It looks like the DisableIMDSv1 option might be a new addition to the available beanstalk settings options. [Added June 2020](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/relnotes/release-2020-06-10-imdsv2.html).

Is this a terraform issue where they don't have the option available or I need to upgrade to terraform 0.13.x? I'm using `terraform version 0.12.23` with `aws provider 3.2.0`. I ran a `terraform init -upgrade` which bumped up my aws provider from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0 thinking that might fix it but I'm still seeing the `Unknown configuration setting` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for EB environments based on **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1). I think the option is not supported for AL1. But it worked for me in AL2.

Below is an example that I use. I also use `setting` as a name of settings, rather then `launch_configuration` and `disable_imds_v1` as in your case.

For example, I used [aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment):

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "ebenv" {

  # ...

  # DisableIMDSv1 option will NOT work in AL1 
  #solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.9 running PHP 7.2"

  # but it will work with AL2 
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.0 running PHP 7.4"
  
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name  = "EC2KeyName"
    value = aws_key_pair.key.key_name
  }
 
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "DisableIMDSv1"
    value     = "true"
  }  
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin! That was the issue. I was using the `64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.15.3 running Docker 19.03.6-ce` solution stack, changing it to the `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.0 running Docker` solution stack got it to apply.